# Pandas - If items in a column equal then append items from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble figuring out a workflow to identify items in a dataframe column that are equal to one another and then if that condition is true, create a new column where the items are appended.

For example, I want to see if the first item in the "name" column, in this example "Chimney", duplicates in the column and if it does then take those duplicating rows and append paths from the path column.

I've tried using iloc with an IF condition but was only able to evaluate the first set of matches based on the index. Also tried looking into the [.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) function but had no luck appending items in a separate column once duplicates were found.

```
dict = {'name':["Chimney", "Chimney", "Columbia", "Washington","Washington","Washington"],
        'Path': ["Path1", "Path2", "Path3", "Path 4", "Path 5", "Path 6"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

 
    name        Path
0   Chimney     Path1
1   Chimney     Path2
2   Columbia    Path3
3   Washington  Path4
4   Washington  Path5
5   Washington  Path6
```

What I am looking for:

```
    name        Append_Path
0   Chimney     Path1, Path2
2   Columbia    Path3
3   Washington  Path4, Path5, Path6
```

The code below is what I thought was on the right track but now feel that this logic won't accomplish what I am trying to do.

```
n = 0

for i in df["name"]:
    n += 1

    if df["name"].iloc[n] == df["name"].iloc[n+1]:
        df["Append_Path"] = df["Path"].iloc[n] + ", " + df["Path"].iloc[n+1]
    else:
        pass
```

Any Help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby("name").Path.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x)).reset_index()
#          name                    Path
# 0     Chimney            Path1, Path2
# 1    Columbia                   Path3
# 2  Washington  Path 4, Path 5, Path 6
```